# Array of pointers in c, accessing the original array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a question about array of pointers in C: assume we have the following code

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
int *parr[3];

for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    parr[i] = &arr[i];
```

Why are `*(*(parr + 2))` and `*(*parr +2)` equal and both pointing to the 3rd element in `arr`? I understand the first one but not the second expression.

Comment: Because the block of RAM is contiguous and the + operator uses sizeof(int *) on the left side of this:  &parr[0]  + 2 == &parr[0 + 2]

Answer (score 2):

Here is your `arr` in memory:

```
  Content               Address
+---------------------+
| arr[0] = 0x00000001 | 0xaaaa00000000 = arr
| arr[1] = 0x00000002 | 0xaaaa00000004
| arr[2] = 0x00000003 | 0xaaaa00000008
| ...                 | 0xaaaa00000010
```

Here is yout `parr` in memory:

```
  Content                    Address
+--------------------------+
| parr[0] = 0xaaaa00000000 | 0xbbbb00000000 = parr
| parr[1] = 0xaaaa00000004 | 0xbbbb00000008
| parr[2] = 0xaaaa00000008 | 0xbbbb00000010
| ...                      | 0xbbbb00000018
```

When you do `*(*(parr + 2)`, you are getting:

```
*(*(parr + 2))   *(*(0xbbbb00000000 + 2*sizeof(int*)))
== *(parr[2])    *(*(0xbbbb00000010))
== *(&arr[2])    *(0xaaaa00000008)
== arr[2]        0x00000003
```

When you do `*(*parr + 2)`, you are getting:

```
*(*parr + 2)        *(*(0xbbbb00000000) + 2*sizeof(int))
== *((&arr[0])+2)   *(0xaaaa00000000 + 2*sizeof(int))
== *(arr+2)         *(0xaaaa00000008)
== arr[2]           0x00000003
```

---

You may be wondering why `arr + 2` is not equal to `0xaaaa00000000 + 2 == 0xaaaa00000002`, that's because pointer arithmetic is different than normal integer arithmetic. When you do this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}
```

That's an array of 3 integers, each `sizeof(int) == 4` bytes long, so 12 bytes in total. You can see this clearly from my drawing  above.

When you do:

```
arr + 1
```

That's skipping `sizeof(int) == 4` bytes, thus skipping the first integer to get to the second.

The compiler does all of this for you transparently,so you don't really notice it. Each time you do something like `arr[i]`, it really is `*(<address_of_arr> + i * sizeof(<type>))`.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Added a bit of explanation on pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of pointers here.  Take a deep breath.

`*(*(parr + 2))` says, "take the second element of `parr`, and dereference it".  This is equivalent to `*parr[2]`.

`*(*parr + 2)` says, "take the first pointer pointed to by `parr`, add 2 to it, and dereference".  It is equivalent to `*(parr[0] + 2)`.

This all works because `parr` isn't a simple pointer to `int` (which is the type of pointer we usually use to access arrays of `int`), but rather, an array of three pointers to `int`.  The situation looks like this:

```
      +-----+-----+-----+
 arr: |  1  |  2  |  3  |
      +-----+-----+-----+
         ^     ^     ^
         |     |     |
      +--|--+--|--+--|--+
parr: |  *  |  *  |  *  |
      +-----+-----+-----+
```

So it's easy to see how `*parr[2]` works; it just chases the third pointer in `parr`.

To see how the other expression works, let's first throw an ordinary pointer-to-`int` into the mix.  Let's write

```
int *ip = arr;
```

(This is, as I said earlier, "the type of pointer we usually use to access arrays of `int`".)  This gives us

```
      +-----+-----+-----+
 arr: |  1  |  2  |  3  |
      +-----+-----+-----+
         ^
         |
      +--|--+
  ip: |  *  |
      +-----+
```

Now, it's a hallmark of C that a pointer-to-`int` accesses an array-of-`int` perfectly, just as well as the original array did.  (Actually this is true for any pointer-to-T and array-of-T.)  `p` points to `a[0]`, but by pointer arithmetic, `p+1` points to `a[1]`, and `p+2` points to `a[2]`.

In fact, when we say `*p`, that's actually `p[0]`, which is actually `a[0]`.  When we say `*(p+1)`, that's actually `p[1]`, which is actually `a[1]`.  When we say `*(p+2)`, that's actually `p[2]`, which is actually `a[2]`.  Etc.

But the `ip` I defined is the same pointer as your `parr[0]`.  So `*(*parr + 2)` is `*(ip + 2)` which is `a[2]`.

Now, I blew past something which it sounds like you haven't really learned yet.  I said,

> It's a hallmark of C that a pointer-to-`int` accesses an array-of-`int` perfectly, just as well as the original array did.

By definition, when I have a pointer-to-type-T, and I add 1 to that pointer, the compiler makes it point to the next element in a conceptual array of T.  So under the hood, the compiler doesn't add 1 to the address, it actually adds `sizeof(T)` to the address.  For a pointer to `int`, on a 32-bit machine, that means adding 4, as you saw.

How does the compiler know how to do this?  Well, this is the reason that pointers have types, the reason that they know what type they point to.  When we declare

```
int *ip;
```

we are not just declaring `ip` to be a pointer; we are very specifically declaring it to be a pointer to `int`.  So the compiler always knows it points to `int`s, so it always knows to multiply by 4 when doing pointer addition (and to divide by 4 when doing pointer subtraction, but that's another story).

And if this was your question, you need to skip to the chapter in your C book that talks about pointer arithmetic in C, and the special relationship between pointers and arrays.  There are zillions of questions and answers here on Stack Overflow discussing that relationship, but I'm not sure which is the canonical one, so just now I can't point you at one.

Comment: what confuses me really is, in the 2nd expression *(*ptr + i),  *ptr is basically an address VALUE, say 0xFFFF, when incrementing it, why does it increase by 4 as an integer pointer, I know its an address of an integer, but HOW does it know?

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks! so basically if it was an array of char pointers, char * carr[3], and i pointed to the int array, *(*carr +1) would point to the 2nd byte of the first element? Am I right?

Comment: Um, right.  Or if you declared a simple `char *cp` and pointed it to the array.  (Whether it's a good idea to be pointing at the individual bytes in an `int` is another question.  You can and sometimes need to, but then you get to learn about endianness...)

Comment: However if i use char * cp and pointed in the array, accessing the 2nd byte would be *(cp + i) I guess, since really cp = *carr = carr[0] I would say.

Comment: Just so.  (Both your `parr` and your `carr` are foreign to me because they contain unnecessary, redundant information.  Basically `parr[1]` precomputes -- or caches the result of -- `parr[0] + 1`.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to comment :)

> *I have a little note.*

when the C compiler encounter an expression like a[i] it's transform it to an expression like *(a+i).

Comment: Now that is a good little note, which nowhere in my overly long answer did I manage to mention!